# Dual-core iPad (A5) = Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, grand-central-dispatch, ipad-2

Does the iPhone SDK have support for Grand Central Dispatch, to allow us to take advantage of the multiple cores in the new iPad's CPU?

Comment: Not to mention, it could also improve performance on single core chips, so you should use it before and after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, since iOS 4.0 there is GCD support in iOS. And the normal threading API (pthread and NSThread) is available since iOS 2.0